# awk increment the input field while looping

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have a for loop over an array. I am currently always looking on the $11 field. However, now what I want to do is to check a different field every time.

- When `i` is the first element, I want to look at `$11` field.
- When `i` is the second element, I want to look at `$12` field.
- When `i` is the third, I want to look at `$13` field.

I am currently using:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    awk -v OFS="\t" -v str1="$i" -v thr="$THR" '{ if($11>=thr)  print "chr" $1, $2 ,$3 , str1 ;}' comb.txt > $i".bed"    
done
```

How can I do this?

My variables are as follows:

```
STR1="CD45RA+_naive"
STR2="CD45RO+_mem"
STR3="CD127-_Treg"
STR4="IL17-_Th_stim_MACS"
STR5="IL17+_Th17_stim"
array=($STR1 $STR2 $STR3 $STR4 $STR5)
THR=10
```

Comment: please add a small set of sample data, and the required output from that data. 2 lines should be enough. Good luck.

Comment: it is not about the output, it is about having instead of $11 an $12 next round, just incrementing the field I am looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an array `names`, you can loop through its values and know the index by doing:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#names[@]}; i++))
do
   echo "$i, ${names[$i]}"
done
```

For example,

```
$ names=('a' 'b' 'c')
$ for ((i=0; i<${#names[@]}; i++)); do echo "$i, ${names[$i]}"; done
0, a
1, b
2, c
```

Based on this logic, in your case you can say:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++))
do
   awk -v index="$i" -v str1="${names[$i]}" -v thr=$THR '{ if($(index+11)=>thr) ... }' comb.txt
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
done
```

That is, you are providing the index $i as `index` to awk and the value `${names[$i]}` as `str`. Then, within the awk code you can play around with the index value, by saying `index + 10` or whatever you need to do with that number.

Comment: @Tensibai thanks for the edit! Since I was also editing there seem to be a conflict between our versions (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29395267/revisions) and I cannot see what you changed. Feel free to do it again!

Comment: It was just a small typo on the first line (`namese` instead of `names`) :)

Comment: Finally I did a small improvement on the way to do math to access a field within awk, the `$()` is not intuitive for all I think

Comment: @Tensibai nice! I didn't go into OP's logic, thanks for adding this.